# How to disable Product Image Popup

Tags: magento2, zoom

In my product detail page, My product image can be Zoom/in and Popup(large image).

I only want product image to be "zoom/in" option.

How can I disable the popup image ?

Answer (score 4):

Check `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`.
If your theme is somehow similar with the default one you should find something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
```

Focus on the `popWin`. That one opens the image in a new page.
Remove this link and insert your logic for zoom in the same file.

Comment: i removed those line, stil showing exactly the same window popup.

Comment: Maybe you modified the wrong file. Enable [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/) to see what you need to modify:

Answer (score 0):

To disable the popup of product image, `etc/view.xml` and change this code.

```
<var name="gallery">
    <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
</var>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in **app\design\frontend\VENDOR\YOUR_THEME\etc\view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
        <var name="gallery">
            <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
        </var>
    </vars>
</view>
```